# javascript read text from file does not show up on browser

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to show text fetched from local file on the chrome browser, but it does not show up.

I run the script on localhost. The code is as follows:

```js
var target = document.getElementById("my-element");
var content = null;
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
xhr.open("GET", "content.txt");
xhr.onload = () => {
  content = xhr.response.split(/\r?\n/);
  let counter = 0;
  setInterval(() => {
    target.innerHTML = content[counter++ % content.length];
    setTimeout(() => target.innerHTML = "", 500);
  }, 1000);
};
xhr.send();
```

```html
<div>
  <span id="my-element" class=" css-1yy09vp" data-font-weight="semibold"></span>
</div>
```

Comment: Local file from where?

Comment: from my computer

Comment: Is the file being served by a server (locally)?

Comment: The file is under the same folder with the html file.

Comment: That doesn’t mean it’s available to the browser. Remember, the browser doesn’t have direct access to your computer folders. The file needs to be served by a server

Comment: How can I do it? The browser has access to my html files, why not to the text file?

Comment: `XMLHttpRequest` works with http(s) protocol, if you're opening an html file using file protocol, you can't make a XMLHttpRequest to a relative URL, because that contains the file protocol. You've to install a server to your local machine to get XMLHttpRequests to work, or use [FileReader API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) instead.

Comment: What would be the proper command for that? I need to read text from the file, and keep it line by line in an array.

Comment: Alternatively save a js object or string and load it like this: `<span id="my-element" class=" css-1yy09vp" data-font-weight="semibold"></span>
</div><script src="content.js"></script><script>document.getElementById("my-element").textContent = txt;</script>` where content.js is `const txt = \`content here\nmore lines\nevven more lines\``

Comment: @yusuf Maybe not worth of nothing, but Majid Laissi'd answer in the linked dup does not work anymore in modern browsers. I've last seen it working in Firefox around the end of 2017, after that non of the modern browsers has supported file protocol with XHR requests to the local file systems.

Comment: Thank you for the answer, @mplungjan. However, it shows the whole text file. I want each the text at each line blink one by one, sequentially.

Comment: So merge them: `const target = document.getElementById("my-element"), content = txt.split(/\r?\n/);
  let counter = 0;
  setInterval(() => {
    target.innerHTML = content[counter++ % content.length];
    setTimeout(() => target.innerHTML = "", 500);
  }, 1000);`